# how to apply chow test for panel data analysis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, panel-data

I have a dataset of 32 countries, over 21 years (1992-2012). I'm checking the existence of an inverted U-shape relationship between logCO2  (dependent variable) and  logGDP (other explanatory variables: logGDP^2, Energy cons, Urbanization). Applying a simple OLS (pooled) and an Individual Fixed Effect, the hypothesis of inverted U-shape relationship holds. 
I want to test if in year 2004, does exist a structural change. How can I do it applying the Chow test?
I applied a dummy (Dummy = 0 for year <2005, Dummy = 1 for year 2005 and on).

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to panel data, we are using the Chow Test to check for **poolability**, where the null hypothesis assumes homogeneous slope coefficients.

To test this, one would apply an *F-Test* across both a restricted an unrestricted model.

[image: equation]

To clarify, a restricted model is one where at least some of the coefficients of the independent variables are assumed to be zero, and hence this would apply to any models with omitted variable.

One useful way of doing this in R is using [pooltest](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plm/versions/1.6-5/topics/pooltest). In this example, you can see that an F Test is being carried out across the "within" and "pooling" models to determine whether a structural break exists, i.e. how poolable is the data.